# User types in field & outputs certain text in new line (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

Background on questions - I am trying to create a fighting game notation converter with javascript but I am getting no where. I cannot find online anywhere with something like this which I feel like there probably is plenty of stuff like this! But I am new to javascript so I am probably searching poorly.

Question - How would you code/write in javascript something that would have a user write/copy paste some text into a field for example 2H, 6H, 236S and it would output on a line below the following Down B, Forward B, Quarter Circle Forward A.

I have ideas for this like creating conditionals like

if (input === 2H) {
return 'Down B'};

But I just don't know where to start and how to write it correctly. I don't mind trying stuff on my own so if you know a guide that would be similar to this so I can learn feel free to send me one or if you want to write some sample code that could point me in the right direction! Anything would help!

Comment: If you just want a relationship between one string and another, an object would do. i.e. `{ "2H" : "Down B" }["2H"] == "Down B";`

Comment: Ok that seems great! How would one integrate that into the input field and then have it output the converted text?

Comment: You would define the object before you need it, something like `const myObj = {  "2H" : "Down B", "Key2" : "Value2" }` then when you need the related value, you can just call `myObj[key]` and you will have the related value. No if statement needed. I imagine it would look something like `myObj[input]` for you, which would equate the related val.

Comment: Hmm I still can't really picture how that code would look for a input field when somebody types 2H into it and it shoots back Down B in a field below the input. :/ Hopefully it clicks eventually but im not seeing it currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are asking for a demonstration of a textarea that can update some div in live time, replacing valid keys with their related value.

I first define the object `s2mObj` which aims to define a relationship between a key string and its value.

Then I grab the textarea element from the dom, and add an event listener to the `keyup` event. Whenever the key is released, I am going to execute the block of code inside, which is described as follows:

I will store the current input value into a constant variable named `input`

I preform some very basic validation of input using regex, before processing I replace all the characters that I would consider invalid with an empty string. I do this because 2H, as a string will not be found as a key however 2H will be, so by removing unexpected characters while I process, I avoid problems. This is mainly for demonstration purposes. You could add validation that fits your needs.

I take the validated/stripped input and split by spaces, the delimiter of choice. Now I have an array of each string segment. I map the array, and either replace with the value it is a key for, or the string err if it is not a valid key.

Now that I have processed the array, I convert back to a string with the `.join` method, adding a comma to separate values.

Finally, I replace the innerText of my output area with the formatted string.

Hopefully this is helpful for you.

```js
let s2mObj = {
  "2H" : "Down B",
  "6H" : "Forward B",
  "236S" : "Quarter Circle Forward A",
}

document.querySelector("textarea")
.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  const input = e.target.value;
  const inputValidated = input.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "");
  const arrOfIns = inputValidated.split(" ");
  const arrOfOuts = arrOfIns.map(e => s2mObj[e] ? s2mObj[e] : "err");
  const out = arrOfOuts.join(", ");
  document.getElementById("output").innerText = out;
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

textarea, div {
  width: 40%;
  min-height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Try typing `2H 6H 236S` into the snippet!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I am going to work with this and I will post my finished code when I'm done! Thanks so much!!

Comment: Could you explain what this line is? input.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, ""); It looks like a few random letters and numbers within the parentheses. Lol

Comment: This might help with beginning to understand Regular Expressions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean